# AlarmManager: Alarm is not getting triggered after a value exceeds a certain limit

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want to set up an alarm that will get triggered after a value received from Ubidots in real-time is exceeds a certain limit(in this case, the limit set is 10000). Part of the codes in MainActivity.java are those which implements some other functionality(getting sensor values from Ubidots and plotting it in a graph in my mobile app and this functionality does work)

The alarm is however not getting triggered. Here is what I have done so far:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private TextView mTextMessage;
 private static GraphicalView view;
 private LineGraph line = new LineGraph();
 private static Thread thread;

 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    thread = new Thread() {
        public void run()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <1000; i++)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Point p = UbidotsData.getDataFromReceiver(i); // We got new data!
                line.addNewPoints(p); // Add it to our graph
                view.repaint();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    view = line.getView(this);
    setContentView(view);
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public void scheduleAlarm(View V)
{

    // Create an Intent and set the class which will execute when Alarm triggers
    // Adding AlarmReceiver in the Intent, the onRecieve() method of this class will execute when
    // alarm triggers
    Intent intentFireAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    // create the object
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;

    //set the alarm for particular time
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentFireAlarm, 0);

    //Ubidots Client
    ApiClient api1 = new ApiClient("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    Variable ldr1 = api1.getVariable("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    Value[] values = ldr1.getValues();
    int newData = (int) values[0].getValue();

    if(newData>30000) {
        alarmManager.set(alarmType, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), alarmIntent);
        }

    }
}


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(TAG,"Alarm Notification received");

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.teerna.smartagriculturev5">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This part(taken from the Ubidots API) below does fetch sensor values in real-time in the line chart on the mobile app therefore I am not sure if that could be an issue:

```
ApiClient api1 = new ApiClient("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
Variable ldr1 = api1.getVariable("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
Value[] values = ldr1.getValues();
int newData = (int) values[0].getValue();
```

Comment: Stop using `AlarmManager`. have a look at firebase jobdispatcher https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: Please suggest what I can change in the post to add more details in it before downvoting the question.

Comment: Why are you using `AlarmManager` for this? Alarms are meant to trigger based on time, not some arbitrary variable value.

Comment: @MikeM. What could be a possible solution to this? I wanted the alarm to trigger in real-time, like when the sensor value just exceeds the limit.

Comment: I am completely new to Android, I need some help getting along with it.

Comment: @KasimRangwala I checked out FirebaseJobDispatcher. I can't however fire out how to trigger an alarm using that. Or do I just have to play an audio using `MediaPlayer` in the OnStart method after the sensor value is exceeds the limit set?

Comment: @MikeM. Is the approach I mentioned above correct?

Comment: Not as far as I'm gathering from the described desired behavior. As mentioned, alarms are meant to fire at specific times, not based on some other arbitrary value. If you want to send a broadcast to a `BroadcastReceiver`, just do it directly; i.e., with `Context#sendBroadcast(Intent)`. It also doesn't really make sense to do this during a click method (I'm assuming the `scheduleAlarm(View V)` method is an `onClick` method). You would do it whenever the your data reaches the expected value. I would imagine there's some sort of callback event you can register for, or subscribe to, with Ubidots.

Comment: That's where you'd do the `if(newData>30000)` check, and send the broadcast. As you have it now, the `AlarmManager` is rather pointless, 'cause you only schedule the alarm during a click, when the value is >30000, and it's scheduled to fire immediately.

Comment: @MikeM. I am not sure of what "callback event" you are referring to. Here is the Ubidots Java API if that make it clear for both of us: https://github.com/ubidots/ubidots-java

Comment: Yup, I get it that the `scheduleAlarm(View V)` is rather pointless as there is no click.

Comment: @MikeM. I'll do it directly using `Context.sendBroadcast(Intent)`. Thanks a lot for the help